# Azure VM Subdomain

Tags: iis, virtual-machines, azure, subdomain

I have an Azure VM and I've pointed it with my domain. I wish to know if it is possible to create a subdomain that points to a new site on the same VM

PS - It is a Windows server 2012 and I use IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible to do this. The technology you are looking for is called Name Based Virtual Hosting.

Comment: A point of clarification: In IIS in Windows the term is Host Headers.